# Gigabyte u24f Touchpad (elantech) not detected

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, elantech

A new Ubuntu user here. I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my gigabyte U24F laptop. At first the touch-pad (I believe it's elantech) was working fine but one day I turned it off using fn+f10 key from the keyboard. The next day I could no longer turn it back on and it has since been undetected by the system.

```
xinput returns

Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Optical Mouse                id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

so there's no touch-pad detected. I'm using a USB mouse at the moment.

Attempting to run synclient gives

```
"Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?"
```

Things I've tried so far to no avail

- Reinstalling xserver-xorg-input-synaptics.
- Checking dconf.editor settings, touchpad is enabled.
- Booting into a live usb session, touchpad no longer even works in this case. (Does this mean a fresh install wouldn't even solve the problem?)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: See related kernel bug report : [https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=81331](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=81331)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

> cat /proc/bus/input/devices | grep Name

Output should include > Elantech Touchpad

If so download the following

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1166442/+attachment/3941591/+files/psmouse-elantech-x551c.tar.gz

Open a terminal, and follow these steps

> cd ~/Downloads
>   sudo dkms ldtarball psmouse-elantech-x551c.tar.gz
>   sudo dkms install -m psmouse -v elantech-x551c
>
> sudo rmmod psmouse
>   sudo modprobe psmouse

HTH

**Reference**

- [Ubuntu activate multi touch on elantech](https://askubuntu.com/questions/508211/elantech-touchpad-not-detected-as-ps-2-in-exo-nifty-7385?answertab=oldest#tab-top)
- [ElanTech TouchPad NOT detected as PS/2 in EXO NIFTY 7385](https://askubuntu.com/questions/508211/elantech-touchpad-not-detected-as-ps-2-in-exo-nifty-7385?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I have tried
'cat /proc/bus/input/devices | grep Name'
Output: [link](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/8037100/)
There's no device named Elantech Touchpad or anything like a touch pad. I also followed the rest of the steps but nothing changed. 
Could it be that the key fn+f10 used to turn on and off the touchpad is conflicting with something in ubuntu?

Comment: Not too sure about the fn+f10 comb, almost looks like the touchpad is not getting loaded. Try the suggestions from this link. http://askubuntu.com/questions/237059/elantech-touchpad-stopped-working-after-restart?rq=1 or this suggestions from this link http://askubuntu.com/questions/256106/how-can-i-disable-elantech-touchpad-while-typing-on-ubuntu-12-10?rq=1

Comment: Thanks. I tried them but they don't work for me. I think my problem is different. My touchpad is not even detected in my devices list. The solutions above are for the case where it is (wrongly) detected as a psmouse.

Comment: There are three similar thread, with similar symptoms, there could be a bug. Might want to log a bug report. Here is a link. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection